# android setPositiveButton& setNegativeButton make broken button in sdk level 26

Tags: android, android-dialog

This is my code

```
case DIA_SURRENDER:
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.booksmall)
        .setTitle(R.string.END_OF_DUEL)
        .setMessage(R.string.END_OF_DUEL2)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.BUTTON_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(Duel_CalculatorActivity.this, R.string.INITIALIZE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Initialize();
                }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.BUTTON_cancel, null)
        .create();
```

[This is the dialog in old version. And I want the same one in new version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxS5e.png)

[But in sdk26, the dialog shown as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlV1q.png)

The old version and new version use same code for this dialog.
How can I recover the old version dialog?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.booksmall)
            .setTitle(R.string.END_OF_DUEL)
            .setMessage(R.string.END_OF_DUEL2)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    quit();
                }
            }).create().show();
```

---

**Style**

```
  <style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorTag</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think my project is too old to import parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert". In my style.xml it does'n work. How can i imoprt 
 <parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 27